# SQL Average set of Group By Results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am doing the following query to get the count of bookings grouped by week.

```
SELECT 
  Count([Id]) as Sessions
  FROM [RitualDB].[dbo].[SessionBooking]
  Where MemberId = 1
  Group by DATEPART(WEEK, Date)
```

This returns me a nice set of results.  What i want to do is get the average of all these results.  I have tried

```
SELECT 
  AVG(Count([Id])) as average
  FROM [RitualDB].[dbo].[SessionBooking]
  Where MemberId = 1
  Group by DATEPART(WEEK, Date)
```

However I get the following error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Can someone give me a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: You could use subquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT AVG(Sessions)
FROM(
    SELECT 
        Count([Id]) AS SESSIONS
    FROM [RitualDB].[dbo].[SessionBooking]
    WHERE MemberId = 1
    Group BY DATEPART(WEEK, Date)
)t
```